# pseudocode for sort number array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have problem to get sort array from number array.I want to find efficient way to do this sort.

This is an array i want to algorithm for sort

```
var marks=[10,58,14,05,35];
```

I want to sort like this
05
10
14
35
58

Comment: `console.log(marks.sort(function(a,b){
return a-b;
}));`

Comment: You may have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On such a small chunk of data pretty any alghorithm will be perceivably fast. For example, you could do Insertion Sort like this:

```js
    var arr = [10,58,14,05,35];
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var temp = arr[i];
      for(var j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp < arr[j]; j--) arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
      arr[j + 1] = temp;
    }
console.log(arr);
```

Also it should be noted that there are some other - more/less complicated/efficient - sorting algorithms at your disposal that you might want to learn. In general, the choice depends on your concrete circumstances. Those who asked you this question wanted to see how familiar with algorithms you are. And for the purpose of a job interview Insertion Sort may be a suitable sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [10,58,14,05,35].sort((a,b) => a > b ? 1 : -1 );
console.log(a);
```

More `.sort()` [info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control)

Comment: thnx for help I'm looking for an algorithm

Comment: Won't be more efficient than built in method.

Comment: This is interview question i got. my answer also .sort()  but i want  simple pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Use inbuilt sort method because inbuilt mechanisms are made to be highly efficient.

`var marks=[10,58,14,05,35];
console.log(marks.sort())`